# Equivalent to Trace.Writeline in Windows Metro C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, trace

I am able to use the following to write to the output window in VS 2013 for Windows 8.1  `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test");`

I am wondering if there is an equivalent to `Trace.Writeline` for windows 8.1. Ideally I would like to print messages to the output windows even while running in Release mode.

Comment: See http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Logging-Sample-for-Windows-0b9dffd7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics is probably your friend. Check out http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-136

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am currently using `LoggingSession` as a logging tool for my application however I was hoping there was a way to avoid opening a file every time I run through my code. I guess I will stick to this for now.